# Exception Handling in Struts2 with Spring3

Tags: java, spring, struts2

I am new to these technologies and I am using the following frameworks to develop an application:

- Struts 2
- Spring 3

I am implementing all business logic in Spring so in case any exception has occurred I will show the custom message to the end user.

Could you please explain me how to develop an exception handling functionality in these technologies?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding the best approach is to define some predefined Exceptions for your Business layer and throws these Exception back to your Action classes.

S2 provides a number of way to handle those exception and display them to the user, here are few of them

### Global Exception Handling

Using the Struts 2 framework you can specify in the struts.xml how the framework should handle uncaught exceptions. The handling logic can apply to all actions (global exception handling) or to a specific action. Let's first discuss how to enable global exception handling.

```
 <global-exception-mappings>
    <exception-mapping exception="org.apache.struts.register.exceptions.SecurityBreachException" result="securityerror" />
     <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="error" />
   </global-exception-mappings>

  <global-results>
        <result name="securityerror">/securityerror.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
   </global-results>
```

Even if you want a fine level control you are free to configure exception handling at per Action basis

```
 <action name="actionspecificexception" class="org.apache.struts.register.action.Register" method="throwSecurityException">
     <exception-mapping exception="org.apache.struts.register.exceptions.SecurityBreachException" 
          result="login" />
      <result>/register.jsp</result>
      <result name="login">/login.jsp</result>
   </action>
```

Its your preference, how you want to configure them.For details refer to the doc

- [Exception-Handling](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/exception-handling.html)

You have even the option to access Exception details from Value-Stack.By default, the `ExceptionMappingInterceptor` adds the following values to the Value Stack:

- exception    The exception object itself
- exceptionStack   The value from the stack trace

and here is the way to access those object in JSP

```
 <s:property value="%{exception.message}"/>
 <s:property value="%{exceptionStack}"/>
```

For details refer to the details

- [Exception-Configuration](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/exception-configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can pick those

[Struts 2](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/exception-handling.html)

[Spring 3](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-3-mvc-exception)

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Here i am implementing all the business logic in spring and presentation in struts. If exception is occurred in business logic level how can i handle that and show the custom error page to end user. Please explain me the steps to achieve this functionality.